# Number of roots of an equation over complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given that $\displaystyle x\in \mathbb{C}$ , how many roots does the equation $\displaystyle x=\sqrt{-4} +\sqrt{-1}$ have?

Here are my solving steps

$\displaystyle x=2i+i$

$\displaystyle x=3i$

$\displaystyle x^{2} =-9$

$\displaystyle x^{2} +9=0$

$\displaystyle ( x-3i)( x+3i) =0$

$\displaystyle x=3i\ $and $\displaystyle x=-3i$

I got 2 roots but was marked wrong on an exam and the correct answer is 4 roots. Can someone explain how there are 4 roots? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are two square roots of $-1$:  $\;i$ and $-i$.  You assumed $x=3i$ and concluded $x=3i$ or $x=-3i$?

Comment: To be clear, are you asking how many different numbers are of the form $\alpha + \beta$ and what they are where $\alpha$ is **a square root** of $-4$ and $\beta$ is **a square root** of $-1$?  The notation $\sqrt{~~}$ is used for when talking about *principal square roots* and unambiguously gives only one result.  $\sqrt{-4}$ gives one and only one result: $2i$, just like how $\sqrt{9}$ gives one and only one result: $\sqrt{9}=3$.

Comment: If $x = 2i + i = 3i$ then that is that.  THat is one value.   Consider this:  How many answers does $x = 5$ have.  Well $x=5 \implies x^2 = 25\implies x^2 -25 =0\implies (x-5)(x+5) = 0$ so $x = 5$ or $x = -5$.  But we have $x = 5$.  PERIOD!  $x=-5$ is *NOT* a solution because $-5 \ne 5$.  And $-3i \ne 3i$.  Just because $x^2 = -9$ and $y^2 = -9$ does *not* mean $x = y$.  Maybe $x = -y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a very well defined question.  It's not clear what $\sqrt{something}$ means.

If $something \ne 0$ there are always two numbers, $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that $x_1^2 = x_2^2 = something$ and, is it turns out, it is always the case that $x_2 = -x_1$.

Now by convention $\sqrt{something}$ is *one* specific one of these two values.  *ONE* of them, and *not* the other one.  The other one is $-\sqrt{something}$

For example $\sqrt{25} = 5$ and $\sqrt {25} \ne -5$ even though $(-5)^2 =5^2 =25$. But it is *only* $5$ that is equal to $\sqrt{25}$.  $-5  =-\sqrt{25}$.

....

If we use this convention then $\sqrt{-4}=$ is *one* specific value.  And $\sqrt{-1}$ is *one* specific value.  And $\sqrt{-4} + \sqrt{-1}$ is *one* sum and therefore there is *one* solution to $x = \sqrt{-4} + \sqrt{-1}$.

....

SOmetimes people say $\sqrt{-1} = i$.  and this sets people's teeth on edge.  We define $i$ so that $i^2 = -1$ but we also have $(-i)^2 = i^2 = -i$.  So which value is $\sqrt{-1}$ equal to?  $i$ or $-i$.  Presumably it can't be both.

Well, if people *say* $\sqrt{-1} = i$ then.... $\sqrt{-1} = i$.  And if we want to be consistant we say if $n > 0$ then then $\sqrt{-n} = i\cdot\sqrt n$.

And if we do this convention:

Then $\sqrt{-4} = i\sqrt{4}=2i$ and $\sqrt{-1} = i$.  An so $x = \sqrt{-4} + \sqrt{-1} = 2i + i = 3i$ is *one* answer and there is only one answer.

.....

But I have to tell you, *no* serious mathematician uses the convention.  We know for any $something \in \mathbb C;something\ne 0$ we know that $x^2 = something$ will have *two* solutions.  One is $x_1$ and the other is $x_2 =-x_1$.  But we have no reason or method to declare one of them over the other as *THE* square root of $something$.

And so we define $\sqrt{something}$ *ONLY* when $something \in \mathbb R; something > 0$.  For all other cases we just don't consider $\sqrt {-4}$ to be well defined.

.......

HOWEVER.... if we aske the question.  If $x$ is the sum of *A* square root of $-4$ plus *A* square root of $-1$ we figure:  $-4$ has *two* possible square roots.  One is $2i$ (because $(2i)^2 = 2^2i^2 = 4(-1) = -4$) and the *other* is $-2i$. But we *don't* refer to *either* of them as $\sqrt{-4}$.

And $-1$ has *two* possible square roots: $i$ and $-i$.

So the possible values are

$x=\begin{cases}2i + i = 3i\\-2i + i = -i\\2i -i = i\\-2i -i = -3i\end{cases}$

There are four possible values for $x$.

***IF*** that was the question that was being asked. But the isn't the way the question was written.  The way the question was written is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for this! This was a question on an exam, and my teacher is by no means a serious mathematician. I think he was just trying to get us to remember that any number technically has 2 square roots.

Answer (score 1):

There are two numbers that square to $-4$: $\pm 2\mathrm{i}$.  There are two numbers that square to $-1$: $\pm \mathrm{i}$.  Consequently, all of \begin{align*}
x &= \pm 2 \mathrm{i} \pm \mathrm{i}  \\
    &= \{2 \mathrm{i} + \mathrm{i}, 2 \mathrm{i} - \mathrm{i}, -2 \mathrm{i} + \mathrm{i}, -2 \mathrm{i} - \mathrm{i}\}  \\
    &= \{ 3\mathrm{i}, \mathrm{i}, -\mathrm{i}, -3\mathrm{i} \}
\end{align*}
are roots.

Comment: But does $\sqrt{-4} = \pm 2i$??????

Comment: The question wasn't $x = a + b$ where $a^2 =-4$ and $b^2 = -1$.  The question was $x = \sqrt{-4} +\sqrt{-1}$.   What is $\sqrt{-4}$?

Comment: @fleablood : Depends.  Is that use of the radical a function?  The use in the Question is not; it is a horrible idiom to represent a set of values.  When I first saw it used, I had to ask for an explanation of the bizarre, nonstandard usage.

Answer (score 1):

Squaring both sides introduces extraneous solutions.  An $n$-th degree polynomial over $\Bbb C$ has $n$ roots, by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Therefore there is one solution.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of algebra is a very welcome overkill to solve the problem of "how many roots" are in that equation